# How to isolate LocalStorage in CefSharp browser

Tags: wpf, local-storage, cefsharp

**Question**

Is it possible to have one WPF application running CefSharp with multiple browser tabs *with each tab having its own isolated LocalStorage*?

---

**EDIT: Answer**
It's completely possible.

---

**Problem**

I have found the need to have multiple browser instances in a single WPF application which each act is their own isolated browsers. What this means is that they cannot share *anything*. Think of having a browser where each tab can have their own User, like how Chrome manages users, but in each tab instead of each individual browser.

I came across the Request Context thing pretty fast from here:
https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#request-context-browser-isolation

However, this is not isolating the LocalStorage, which is turning into a pain because some websites store their session token in LocalStorage. What I have now is:

```
BrowserSettings = new RequestContextSettings
            {
                CachePath = cacheFileName,
                PersistSessionCookies = false,
                PersistUserPreferences = false
            };
```

where `cacheFileName` is unique to each tab.

I have also tried disabling LocalStorage using the Command Line Argument `disable-local-storage` but then the website which use LocalStorage for session data don't run at all.

I have a crazy solution in mind where I create another WPF application which is *just* the browser, and embed that application into my own within each tab, but that brings its own set of problems and headaches, and I'm not completely sure that will even work. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: A RequestContext should allow you to isolate local storage. Your sample code above wouldn't even compile as it's incorrect. You must set http://cefsharp.github.io/api/79.1.x/html/P_CefSharp_AbstractCefSettings_RootCachePath.htm and all your can CachePaths need to be located under that.

Comment: @amaitland: Nothing wrong with it compiling, I have a Property in my class named `BrowserSettings` which I glossed over. Regardless I think all I needed was for someone to tell me that it should work and that I'm being an idiot. 

Can confirm, it does completely work. Mistake was on my side because I was setting the RequestContext to a different ChromiumWebBrowser then the one I was binding to the screen. I'm more embarassed that I've been trying to fix this for 3 days without seeing the problem I created for myself. Problem Solved! Thanks a lot!

Comment: The browser has it's own BrowserSettings property,  so it's a very confusing name you've chosen.